# How to switch buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, button

I have 3 buttons: button1, button 2 and button 3. When i start my application button1 is on  top,  button 2 is in the middle and button 3 is down on my screen.

When i press one of these buttons, the buttons must switch from position.
So for example button1 switches with button3 or button1 switches with button2

How should i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this an example something which you want with Animation also...

```
    -(IBAction)button1_Clicked:(id)sender{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect btnframe = button1.frame;
        button1.frame = button3.frame;
        button3.frame = btnframe;
///Also you can switch the buttons with center points of buttons like...
/*
        CGPoint btn1center = button1.center;
        button1.center = button3.center;
        button3.center = btn1center;
*/

     //This bellow two lines for your requirement with change the function behind the buttons also...

       // [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button3_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       // [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

**This is an example from this you get idea for your requirement.**

hope this help you...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an animated solution, using blocks instead of the now old `commitAnimations` :

```
-(IBAction)clickedButton1:(id)sender{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations: ^{

             CGPoint center = button1.center;
             button1.center = button2.center;
             button2.center = center;
    }];

}
```

This code switches the buttons 1 and 2 with an animation.